# two loops together in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

**File**

```
sims 10 500
dettol 45 200
nims 200 540
```

**Code:**

```
for E, w in vb, T.readline():
    name, qty, price = w.split()
    print("you bought" + str(vb[E]) + "from" + name)
```

**Description**

I want to run two loop together, one for a file and one for an array. Also, the expected output for each iteration would be

```
>>> "you bought 1 from nims"
```

if "nims" has 1 quantity.

I used like to do

```
for i, k in j, T.readline:
```

but it's not working.

Comment: whats `j` ? can you add a readable format of your desire output ?

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like `zip`?

Comment: The quality of your question is very low. I second mr/ms sloth in pointing you to `zip`, The usage pattern is something like `for element, line in zip(my_list, my_file_object):` --- That said, I have to warn you that I'd be greatly surprised if `str(vb[E])` does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clarified what `vb` is, but I don't think that loop is doing what you think it does.  First, here's what it looks like to the interpreter:

```
for E, w in (vb, T.readline()):
```

This isn't going to take each element of `vb` and each line of `T`.  Instead, it's going to take `vb` and attempt to unpack it to `E` and `w`, and then do the same thing for `T.readline()` on the second iteration.  For example:

```
>>> a = (1, 2)
>>> b = (5, 6)
>>> for i, j in a, b: print(i, j)

1 2
3 4
```

Notice that it doesn't print the 0th element of `a` and `b`, but both elements of `a` followed by both elements of `b`.  If you wanted to combine them you would use `zip`:

```
>>> for i, j in zip(a, b): print(i, j)

1 3
2 4
```

Finally, `T.readline()` the way you are using it is not going to give you each line of `T`.  Rather, it's going to take the first line in `T` (assuming you don't read other lines prior to the loop) and iterate over the characters of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
with open("test") as T:
    vb = [1, 2, 3]
    for E, w in zip(vb, T):
        name, qty, price = w.split()
        print("you bought {}  from {}".format(E, name))
```

Also note that there were two other errors in your code:

- you want to iterate all the lines in the file `T`, not the letters in the first `T.readline()`
- `E` is already the element from the list, not the index of that element

Note that in Python 2.x, `zip` will consume the entire file at once, so it that file is very large, you probably want to use `itertools.izip` instead, which creates an iterator. In Python 3.x, `zip` itself is an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to paidhima's asnwer, you could maybe consider using `enumerate()` such as

```
for i,line in enumerate(T):
    print i, line
```

assuming that T is the name of your file. This would print

```
0 sims 10 500
1 dettol 45 200
2 nims 200 540
```

Is this what you want?